# Project baseline and software development lifecycle

Tags: software-development

I have a uni assignment that has the following requirement

> "include in your baseline document how the project will include the
>   project management lifecycle and the software development lifecycle"

I have the project baseline but I´m not sure how to align this or put this baseline in any relationship with the project management lifecycle or with the software development lifecycle (in my case waterfall).

Am I misunderstanding the question or how is the relationship between these?

Comment: "Am I misunderstanding the question" is hard to answer when you haven't including your understanding of the question. What about it is confusing you? What do you *think* the relationship is? Why do you think that?

Comment: i dont understand how the project management lifecycle and the sdlc have to be aligned with a project baseline

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misunderstanding the question.

A baseline document is the point at which you start tracking changes. It's the first version of a document that all of the necessary stakeholders agree to.

The assignment is asking you to create a baseline document (which sounds like some kind of project plan). In the baseline document, you need to include information about the project management lifecycle and the software development lifecycle. This means that you cannot produce a baseline document without this information. It also means that if you decide to make changes to the project management lifecycle or software development lifecycle as the project progresses, you will have an original lifecycle to compare the changes against.